# Submitting a form causes a TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'addEventListener')

Tags: javascript, html, json

I am trying to submit a form that queries JSON data saved in localStorage. I want to have it so it transfers the user to another local page named "results.html" and inserts a div class "card" inside another (existing) div #search-results.

```
const data = {
    "properties": [
        {
            "id":"prop1",
            "type":"House",
            "bedrooms":3,
            "price":750000,
            "tenure":"Freehold",
            "description":"Attractive three bedroom semi-detached family home situated within 0.5 miles of Petts Wood station with fast trains to London and within easy walking distance of local shops, schools, bus routes and National Trust woodland. The property comprises; two receptions, fitted 18'9 x 10'1 kitchen/breakfast room and conservatory. The property also benefits from having a utility room and cloakroom. To the first floor there are three bedrooms and a family bathroom with separate WC. Additional features include double glazing, gas central heating and a well presented interior...",
            "location":"Petts Wood Road, Petts Wood, Orpington BR5",
            "picture":"images/prop1pic1small.jpg",
            "url":"properties/prop1.html",
            "added": {
                "month":"October",
                "day":12,
                "year":2022
            }
        },
        {
            "id":"prop2",
            "type":"Flat",
            "bedrooms":2,
            "price":399995,
            "tenure":"Freehold",
            "description":"Presented in excellent decorative order throughout is this two double bedroom, two bathroom, garden flat. <br>The modern fitted kitchen is open plan to the living room which boasts solid wooden floors and includes integrated appliances including a dishwasher & a washing machine. This large open plan benefits from bi folding doors onto a secluded private courtyard garden. Both bedrooms are double sized, and the family bathroom boasts a matching three piece suite a shower attachment over the bath. There is also a separate wet room. There are walnut doors throughout and wiring for Sky TV/aerial points in the living room/kitchen and both bedrooms.<br>This apartment being only five years old, is still under a 10 year building guarantee...",
            "location":"Crofton Road Orpington BR6",
            "picture":"images/prop2pic1small.jpg",
            "url":"properties/prop2.html",
            "added": {
                "month":"September",
                "day":14,
                "year":2022
            }
        },
        {
            "id":"prop3",
            "type":"House",
            "bedrooms":8,
            "price":999995,
            "tenure":"Freehold",
            "description":"Presented in excellent decorative order throughout is this two double bedroom, two bathroom, garden flat. <br>The modern fitted kitchen is open plan to the living room which boasts solid wooden floors and includes integrated appliances including a dishwasher & a washing machine. This large open plan benefits from bi folding doors onto a secluded private courtyard garden. Both bedrooms are double sized, and the family bathroom boasts a matching three piece suite a shower attachment over the bath. There is also a separate wet room. There are walnut doors throughout and wiring for Sky TV/aerial points in the living room/kitchen and both bedrooms.<br>This apartment being only five years old, is still under a 10 year building guarantee...",
            "location":"Buckaroo Road Orpington W12",
            "picture":"images/prop2pic1small.jpg",
            "url":"properties/prop3.html",
            "added": {
                "month":"September",
                "day":14,
                "year":2022
            }
        }
    ]
};


function searchData(searchTerm) {
  const data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('data'));
  const results = data.properties.filter(properties => properties.location.includes(searchTerm));
  return results;
}

localStorage.setItem('data', JSON.stringify(data));

const form = document.getElementById('search-form');
form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  const searchTerm = document.getElementById('search-input').value;
  const results = searchData(searchTerm);

  window.location.assign("results.html");
  window.onload = function() {
    const searchResultsDiv = document.getElementById('search-results');
    if (results.length > 0) {
      results.forEach(result => {
        searchResultsDiv.innerHTML += `
          <div class="card">
            <a href="${result.url}">Link</a>
            <h2>${result.type}</h2>
            <p>Price: ${result.price}</p>
            <p>Location: ${result.location}</p>
          </div>
        `;
      });
    } else {
      searchResultsDiv.innerHTML += '<p>No results found</p>';
    }
  }
});
```

With the code above ^ I am using "window.location.assign" to change pages however that gives the eventListener null error.

```
 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'addEventListener')
```

```
const form = document.getElementById('search-form');
form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  const searchTerm = document.getElementById('search-input').value;
  const results = searchData(searchTerm);



  const htmlElement = document.createElement('html')
  htmlElement.innerHTML = `
    <head>
      <title>Search Results</title>
    </head>
    <body>
      <div id="search-results">
  `;
  if (results.length > 0) {
    results.forEach(result => {
      htmlElement.innerHTML += `
        <div class="card">
            <a href="${result.url}">Link</a>
            <h2>${result.type}</h2>
            <p>Price: ${result.price}</p>
            <p>Location: ${result.location}</p>
          </div>
      `;
    });
  } else {
    htmlElement.innerHTML += '<p>No results found</p>';
  }
  htmlElement.innerHTML += '</div></body>';


  const newWindow = window.open("results.html");
  newWindow.document.write(htmlElement.outerHTML);
});
```

IF instead I use document.createElement to create a new HTML page, all the sudden the form submits correctly.

Here are the contents of index.html

```
 <form id="search-form">
        <input type="text" id="search-input" placeholder="Search...">
        <button type="submit">Search</button>
    </form>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
```

And contents of results.html

```
<body>
    <div id="search-results">

    </div>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
```

I have tried using window.location.href to no avail, triple checking ID's, divs, forms and etc are set up correctly.

TLDR: on form submission transfer user to local page results.html - using window.location.assign() causes addEventListener Null error for the form.

Let me know if my question is unclear and any possible solutions you guys might have.

Comment: Can you check all the indentation and divisions? You may have a minor error there.

Comment: There is no such thing as an “addEventListener Null error”. What is the exact error message? Please [edit] your question and provide a [mre].

Comment: @SebastianSimon I have corrected the post to include the exact error and a minimal reproducible example.